# Get access token using refresh token

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I am currently implementing OAuth2 using **thephpleague/oauth2** library. I have already added the refresh token grant and the access token response already contains the refresh token. However, I don't have any idea how to use that refresh token to get a new access token.

I checked the documentation but I don't see anything about it. The oauth2-client library has methods for it but I'm not going to use that.

My code for the refresh token grant:

```
$server->setRefreshTokenStorage(new RefreshTokenStorage);

$refreshTokenGrant = new \League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\RefreshTokenGrant();
$authCodeGrant = new \League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\AuthCodeGrant();

$server->addGrantType($authCodeGrant);
$server->addGrantType($refreshTokenGrant);
$response = $server->issueAccessToken();
```

My question is how can I test that using the refresh token, I can retrieve a new access token? Do I have to implement a new endpoint different from the one that's used by the authorization code grant?

Here is my code for getting the token. Any comments?

```
public function actionToken(){

    $authCodeModel = new \app\models\OAuth_Auth_Codes;

    if(!isset($_POST['code'])){
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(400,"Required parameter \'code\' is missing or invalid.");
    }

    $result = $authCodeModel->find()->where(['authorization_code' => trim($_POST['code'])])->one();

    if(!empty($result)){

        $user_id = $result->user_id;

        $session2 = new Session();
        $session2->open();

        $server = new AuthorizationServer;
        $server->setSessionStorage(new SessionStorage);
        $server->setAccessTokenStorage(new AccessTokenStorage);
        $server->setClientStorage(new ClientStorage);
        $server->setScopeStorage(new ScopeStorage);
        $server->setAuthCodeStorage(new AuthCodeStorage);
        $server->setRefreshTokenStorage(new RefreshTokenStorage);

        $refreshTokenGrant = new \League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\RefreshTokenGrant();
        $authCodeGrant = new \League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\AuthCodeGrant();

        $server->addGrantType($authCodeGrant);
        $server->addGrantType($refreshTokenGrant);

        $response = $server->issueAccessToken();

        $model = new \app\models\OAuth_Access_Tokens();
        $accessTokenModel = $model->find()->where(['access_token' => $response['access_token']])->one();
        $accessTokenModel->setAttribute('user_id',''.$user_id);
        $accessTokenModel->save(FALSE);

        return json_encode($response);
    }
    else{
        throw new \yii\web\UnauthorizedHttpException("You have provided an invalid authorization code.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the cURL support in PHP it would be:

```
$postData = array(
    "grant_type" => "refresh_token",
    "client_id" => $clientID,
    "client_secret" => $clientSecret,
    "refresh_token" => $refreshToken
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $tokenEndpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$r = json_decode($response);
echo $r->access_token;
```

Edit:
For server side examples see: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/blob/master/tests/unit/Grant/RefreshTokenGrantTest.php, e.g.:

```
$server = new AuthorizationServer();
$grant = new RefreshTokenGrant();
$server->addGrantType($grant);
$server->issueAccessToken();
```

Comment: Thanks Hans. In my implementation, the token endpoint was specifically made to accept the authorization code grant type. I followed the example given in the library. Is there an example for accepting the refresh_token grant type. I'm wondering about the part where the token is generated. In the authorization_code grant, there is an issueToken() method call.

Comment: I'm starting to see what you really want: use my client (first) code against the token endpoint; that's the same endpoint for both grants; there's only one such endpoint dealing with all grants.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly it. I have edited my post to include my code for getting the token. It's weird though that when I change the response type, client authentication fails.